# Reading value of a Label in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to set and read value of a lable in jquery but it returns empty

```
$('label#ringIdLabel').text(jQuery(this).val());
```

It shows label text as xx

but when retrieving with

```
     var ringId = $("#ringIdLabel").val();
```

it turns out to be empty. My lable is defined as

```
        <label  id="ringIdLabel" style="visibility: hidden;"   ><?php echo $mainRing['id'] ?></label>
```

Comment: try with $("#ringIdLabel").text();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve you need to use `text()` function only

```
var ringId = $("#ringIdLabel").text();
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/93/).

Comment: i got confused by another stackoverflow question and used hte val :(

Comment: no problem ... we all are there to make away confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `val()` for `label` because val() looks for value attribute of the tag and label doesn't have one

Try this

```
var ringId = $("#ringIdLabel").text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kugil/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Getting Label Value

```
var x=$("#ringIdLabel").html();
alert(x);
```

Setting Label Value

```
$("#ringIdLabel").html("PhotoShop");
```

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit?